# Extract x rows from matrix based on first occurrence of specific value

Tags: r, matrix, extract

I have a matrix (see structure below) and I'd like to select `x=3` subsequent rows.
The first row should be the row where `data[,11]` is = `'2018-01-01_0130'` (**first** occurrence!). How could I do this?

The number of rows to be selected and the start date should be variables.
Something like:

```
start_date <- "2018-01-01_0130"
```

and

```
rows <- 3

structure(c("278.499099686742", "281.836603879929", "281.253089979291", 
"279.783318564296", "285.362102091312", "283.65794852376", "283.811761811376", 
"285.933408588171", "284.710226729512", "290.374462082982", "274.311960190535", 
"281.336100324988", "246.696371361613", "252.707296982408", "254.526200145483", 
"242.377391904593", "252.634052559733", "246.359447017312", "251.322977393866", 
"255.605334639549", "255.405133217573", "252.419202253222", "236.290780380368", 
"252.707296982408", "256.567278057337", "263.586535230279", "264.538712725043", 
"251.811273545027", "263.386333808303", "256.567278057337", "261.543015837669", 
"266.616412848234", "266.010925620794", "263.066499829292", "244.728537872434", 
"263.828241825104", "275.249488800764", "280.872218981385", "279.824823737144", 
"271.653187647462", "285.252235457301", "279.585558623075", "281.902523860335", 
"284.365977942944", "283.047578334808", "286.931974217296", "263.159276098013", 
"281.602221727371", "258.989226967096", "262.522049620748", "260.720236822963", 
"256.784569844604", "266.367381811142", "262.187566757202", "263.295999020338", 
"264.2262031883", "262.856532484293", "267.361064478755", "250.966521203518", 
"262.522049620748", "275.911130085588", "283.792229965329", "281.411786228418", 
"271.560411378741", "288.211310133338", "280.593890175223", "284.453871250153", 
"286.477858796716", "285.012970343232", "289.41496014595", "261.003448590636", 
"283.626209273934", "274.294869825244", "283.277077525854", "281.353190690279", 
"269.106723219156", "286.971037909389", "278.870204761624", "283.513901159167", 
"286.17267370224", "284.934842959046", "287.598498463631", "257.824640646577", 
"283.140354603529", "264.392223879695", "272.93496504426", "271.467635110021", 
"258.933072909713", "274.861293360591", "268.108157590032", "272.446668893099", 
"274.622028246522", "273.779717385769", "274.622028246522", "248.781395927072", 
"273.054597601295", "236.3884396106", "241.122470796108", "243.874019607902", 
"232.84340955317", "241.283608525991", "236.075930073857", "240.187383666635", 
"244.611346796155", "244.41602833569", "241.015045642853", "228.392590135336", 
"241.068758219481", "276.218756660819", "283.076876103878", "280.50843834877", 
"272.676168084145", "287.669301405549", "281.116367056966", "283.831293657422", 
"285.41581466794", "283.633533716202", "289.070711359382", "263.435163423419", 
"282.781456932425", "2018-01-01_0115", "2018-01-01_0115", "2018-01-01_0115", 
"2018-01-01_0115", "2018-01-01_0115", "2018-01-01_0115", "2018-01-01_0115", 
"2018-01-01_0130", "2018-01-01_0130", "2018-01-01_0130", "2018-01-01_0130", 
"2018-01-01_0130", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0"), dim = c(12L, 12L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "gt")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
data[which(data[,11] == start_date)[1] + 0:3,]
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                      gt 
# [1,] "285.933408588171" "255.605334639549" "266.616412848234" "284.365977942944" "264.2262031883"   "286.477858796716" "286.17267370224"  "274.622028246522" "244.611346796155" "285.41581466794"  "2018-01-01_0130" "0"
# [2,] "284.710226729512" "255.405133217573" "266.010925620794" "283.047578334808" "262.856532484293" "285.012970343232" "284.934842959046" "273.779717385769" "244.41602833569"  "283.633533716202" "2018-01-01_0130" "0"
# [3,] "290.374462082982" "252.419202253222" "263.066499829292" "286.931974217296" "267.361064478755" "289.41496014595"  "287.598498463631" "274.622028246522" "241.015045642853" "289.070711359382" "2018-01-01_0130" "0"
# [4,] "274.311960190535" "236.290780380368" "244.728537872434" "263.159276098013" "250.966521203518" "261.003448590636" "257.824640646577" "248.781395927072" "228.392590135336" "263.435163423419" "2018-01-01_0130" "0"
```

This will run into problems if `start_date` is not found, as in

```r
data[which(data[,11] == "not found")[1] + 0:3,]
#                                       gt
# [1,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# [2,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# [3,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# [4,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

So a more defensible position might be:

```r
ind <- which(data[,11] == "not found")
ind
# integer(0)
if (length(ind) > 0) data[ind[1] + 0:3,]

ind <- which(data[,11] == start_date)
ind
# [1]  8  9 10 11 12
if (length(ind) > 0) data[ind[1] + 0:3,]
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                      gt 
# [1,] "285.933408588171" "255.605334639549" "266.616412848234" "284.365977942944" "264.2262031883"   "286.477858796716" "286.17267370224"  "274.622028246522" "244.611346796155" "285.41581466794"  "2018-01-01_0130" "0"
# [2,] "284.710226729512" "255.405133217573" "266.010925620794" "283.047578334808" "262.856532484293" "285.012970343232" "284.934842959046" "273.779717385769" "244.41602833569"  "283.633533716202" "2018-01-01_0130" "0"
# [3,] "290.374462082982" "252.419202253222" "263.066499829292" "286.931974217296" "267.361064478755" "289.41496014595"  "287.598498463631" "274.622028246522" "241.015045642853" "289.070711359382" "2018-01-01_0130" "0"
# [4,] "274.311960190535" "236.290780380368" "244.728537872434" "263.159276098013" "250.966521203518" "261.003448590636" "257.824640646577" "248.781395927072" "228.392590135336" "263.435163423419" "2018-01-01_0130" "0"
```

---

Side note: it looks as if the way this data was read in is faulty. Seeing numbers as strings and some strings looking like dates suggests that this should really be a `data.frame` instead. Frames allow each column to contain different classes of data (`numeric` in most, `Date` in column 11, and either `integer` or `numeric` in the last `"gt"` column. It is certainly not hard to convert columns 1-10 to numbers, but doing so through strings is much less efficient; it's always better to read in to the correct native class the first time.

Comment: As I understood, it was asked for 3 rows in total, thus `0:2` would be the way. Moreover, using a variable, I'd go with `data[ind[1] + 0:(rows-1),]`

Comment: As I understand it, *"select x=3 subsequent rows"* meant the matched row and then three more. Regardless, we can use `0:3` for my interpretation, `0:2` for your interpretation, or many other unambiguous variants.

Comment: Agreed :) The more important part might be the use of object `rows` as variable.